# python websocket-client Handshake status 400 Bad Request

Tags: python, websocket

I am trying to get wss data. There is no official api of website for websocket.
This image from Google Developer tool.

[image]

```
headers = json.dumps({
'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
'Accept-Language': 'tr-TR,tr;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7',
'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
'Connection': 'Upgrade',
'Cookie': 'blabla.....'
'Host': 'www.bitexen.com',
'Origin': 'https://www.bitexen.com',
'Pragma': 'no-cache',
'Sec-WebSocket-Extensions': 'permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits',
'Sec-WebSocket-Key': 'blablabla.....',
'Sec-WebSocket-Version': '13',
'Upgrade': 'websocket',
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/95.0.4638.69 Safari/537.36'})


ws = create_connection('wss://www.bitexen.com/v2/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=C7EGsqrisOIxGFrrBuNk',headers=headers)
```

[image]

[image]

Actually I don't know the "2probe", "3" datas. But info datas are coming.

When I send the same data,

```
ws.send(json.dumps(42["s_m","DOGETRY"]))

while True:
    try:
        result = ws.recv()
        result = json.loads(result)
        print(result)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        break
```

I got this error message

```
        raise WebSocketBadStatusException("Handshake status %d %s", status, status_message, resp_headers)
websocket._exceptions.WebSocketBadStatusException: Handshake status 400 Bad Request
```

What is the problem, How can I fix this ? It's about with auth I guess, but not sure...

Comment: i imagine you get an error even earlier with your json dumps ... see the api documentation for bitexen I guess... i couldnt find one but maybe its there (the page is in turkish so i couldnt read it)

Comment: There is no official api for websocket, I'm trying to get as unofficial. So Im trying without any doc. @JoranBeasley